# How to perform transition between controllers when using monotouch and storyboard?

Tags: xamarin.ios, storyboard, transition

I have created storyboard using following instructions 
http://docs.xamarin.com/ios/tutorials/Introduction_to_iOS_5#Storyboards

It works as expected.

Then I added new button to MonkeyController and new ViewController to storyboard. This is the code I tried to use in button's click event

```
partial void btnClicked (NSObject sender)
{
    UINavigationController ctrl = this.ParentViewController;
    var screen = new TableRowViewController();
    ctrl.PushViewController(screen, true);
}
```

It opens TableRowViewController, but it's background is black and it does not show any modifications I made on it on storyboard.

Can you help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

I'm no expert yet, but it has been my experience trying to get it to work properly that if one of the sides of the split-view is black, then there is a segue that is illegal.

Hope that helps...